# How to remove the space under the elevated button at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, button, spacing

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddPlaceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/add-place';
  @override
  _AddPlaceScreenState createState() => _AddPlaceScreenState();
}

class _AddPlaceScreenState extends State<AddPlaceScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add new Place data'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('User Inputs'),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: Text('Add Place'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I am getting a space under the elevated button located at the bottom of the page please provide any solution to remove it.

[image]

Comment: it seems ok in both my machine and dart pad, I think it's your simulator issue or where you call from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Please refer below code

Add this piece of code inside ElevatedButton.icon Widget

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, /* Please add this to avoid padding */
),
```

```
class AddPlaceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/add-place';
  @override
  _AddPlaceScreenState createState() => _AddPlaceScreenState();
}

class _AddPlaceScreenState extends State<AddPlaceScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add new Place data'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('User Inputs'),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize
                  .shrinkWrap, /* Please add this to avoid padding */
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: Text('Add Place'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Mention what needs to be changed in the original code along with the code.

Comment: Please check above edited code

Comment: You should always use comments in your code to mark the changes.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: this should be the default!

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. you can used `BottomSheet` also [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Text('User Inputs'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  bottomSheet: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
             
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        // Add your button press function here
        print('Button Pressed');
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.add,
      ),
      label: Text(
        'Add Place',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, `remove the drop shadow` and `extra margin` around the ElevatedButton.

For this set the `elevation to 0`, which removes the drop shadow.

To get rid of that extra margin around the button, use the material tab target size and set it to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`. The MaterialTapTargetSize basically ensures that you have a bigger space you can hit with your finger and if we shrink that by setting it to .shrinkWrap, you  get rid of the extra margin.

**Add this code inside the ElevatedButton:**

```
tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
elevation: 0,
```

So by setting this here, the button now really sits on the end of the screen.